# Ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: php

Помогите правильно написать. Ошибка в:

```
  return 'src="images/avatars/.$user['name_avatar']"';

 function showAvatar($user = false) {
   if($user) {
        $hasAvatar = $user['has_avatar'];
        if($hasAvatar) {
               return 'src="images/avatars/.$user['name_avatar']"'; 
        }else {
              return 'src="images/left_stars.jpg"'; 
       }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return 'src="images/avatars/'.$user['name_avatar'].'"';
```